# What is the unit of Z effective?

Tags: electrons, terminology, units

Z effective is the net positive charge experienced by an electron. But what is the unit of this net charge: coulomb (C) or microcoulomb (μC), or something else?

Comment: What is the charge of a magnesium ion? Which units are you using in your answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an example of terminology which should be taken with a grain of salt.

The term "effective nuclear charge" is often casually symbolized with $Z_\mathrm{eff}.$ This is a universally accepted simplification, but you should keep in mind that the effective nuclear charge is, strictly speaking, $Z_\mathrm{eff}e,$ where $e$ is the [elementary charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge).
Similarly, the full nuclear charge is $Ze,$ where $Z$ is the [atomic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number).

So, it would be more appropriate to refer to $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ as to [effective atomic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_atomic_number) since $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ is defined as a function of $Z$ $(Z_\mathrm{eff} = f(Z_i)).$
For example, the [common form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules) provided in every introductory physical chemistry textbook is

$$Z_\mathrm{eff} = Z − σ,$$

where $σ$ is the shielding constant of the nucleus (empirical dimensionless parameter).

Since $Z$ is dimensionless, so is $Z_\mathrm{eff}.$
However, effective nuclear charge $Z_\mathrm{eff}e$ is not, and can, for instance, be expressed in coulombs (in the SI system $e = \pu{1.602176634E−19 C}).$